# Aggregating/Filtering Mongo Results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection `markets` filled with betting markets. My data in the collection looks like this:

```
{ "team" : "Milan", "back" : 1.0, "lay" : 1.0, "btotal" : 7.0, "ltotal" : 6.0 },
{ "team" : "Chelsea", "back" : 1.0, "lay" : 1.0, "btotal" : 1.0, "ltotal" : 1.0 },    
{ "team" : "Arsenal", "back" : 1.0, "lay" : 1.0, "btotal" : 1.0, "ltotal" : 1.0 },
{ "team" : "Milan", "back" : 3.0, "lay" : 3.0, "btotal" : 1.0, "ltotal" : 18.0 }
```

I want to display my data as a list of unique names, the highest `btotal` and the corresponding `back` odds from that row, the highest `ltotal` and its corresponding `lay` odds.
From the above example, the data returned should be this:

```
{"team":"Milan", "back":1.0, "lay":3.0, "btotal":7.0, "ltotal":18.0},
{"team":"Chelsea", "back":1.0, "lay":1.0, "btotal":1.0, "ltotal":1.0},    
{"team":"Arsenal", "back":1.0, "lay":1.0, "btotal":1.0, "ltotal":1.0}
```

This is the output as in the `btotal` in the first occurrence of `"team":"Milan"` is greater than the second occurrence therefore the `back` odds is returned with that, and the `ltotal` in the second occurrence of `"team":"Milan"` is higher than the first therefore the `lay` odds from that row are returned.

Any ideas on how to structure this query in Mongo or Mongoose would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use mapReduce?

The map function

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this.team, this);
}
```

and the reduce function:

```
var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var res = values[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i].btotal > res.btotal) {
                    res.back = values[i].back;
                    res.btotal = values[i].btotal;
            }
            if (values[i].ltotal > res.ltotal) {
                    res.lay = values[i].lay;
                    res.ltotal = values[i].ltotal;
            }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Perform the map-reduce operation:

```
db.markets.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "mpmarkets"});
```

Producing the expected output using $project (aggregation):

```
cursor = db.mpmarkets.aggregate([{
    $project: {_id:0, 
    team: "$_id", 
    back: "$value.back",
    lay: "$value.lay",
    btotal: "$value.btotal",
    ltotal: "$value.ltotal"} },
    {$sort: {team: -1}
}]);
```

Printing the result:

```
while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
    printjson( cursor.next() );
}
```

Result:

```
{ "team" : "Milan", "back" : 1, "lay" : 3, "btotal" : 7, "ltotal" : 18 }
{ "team" : "Chelsea", "back" : 1, "lay" : 1, "btotal" : 1, "ltotal" : 1 }
{ "team" : "Arsenal", "back" : 1, "lay" : 1, "btotal" : 1, "ltotal" : 1 }
```